# strange binomial coefficient identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Can someone please show why the following holds:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}q^{n-k} = p \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}q^{n-k} $$

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thank you for commenting.

This is from Blitzstein and Hwang, p143.

The LHS can be transformed to:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}q^{n-k} = \binom{n-1}{-1}q^{n-k} + p\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}q^{n-k} $$

The identity holds if $$ \binom{n-1}{-1}q^{n-k} = 0. $$

Comment: On the left side, at $k=0$ the binomial coefficient becomes $\binom{n-1}{-1}.$ How is that defined?

Comment: This is exactly why I am asking this question. I found it in Blitzstein and Hwang, p 143

Comment: $\dbinom{n}{k} = 0$ for negative $k$ is a common convention.

Comment: @darijgrinberg It would be really good if you care to add enough contexts for this PSQ.

Comment: @Saad: The OP has just done this after you commented, so I consider this resolved.

Comment: If negatives in lower entry of binomial coefficients imply zero value, that could have been done on both sides, so the lower index of the sums could be $1$ on each side. But that seems odd to do if convention only used on one side.

Comment: @darijgrinberg A trivial (or _______ as called by you) reformulation is not enough context. So I consider it not resolved. You could kindly add full solutions as contexts.

Comment: @coffeemath: This depends on what the author wants to do with the sum :)

Comment: @coffeemath: Don't know what your last comment means, but the best way to define $C(n,k)$ is via base cases $C(n,0) = 1$ for $n∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $C(0,k) = 0$ for $k∈\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and the recurrence $C(n+1,k+1) = C(n,k)+C(n,k+1)$ for $n∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $k∈\mathbb{N}$. This makes Newton series work correctly even for doubly-infinite sequences (see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820)). One sees that $D_n C(n,k+1) = C(n,k)$ where $D_n f(n) := f(n+1)-f(n)$, and so $D_n$ does a left-shift on the Newton series coefficients. Now observe that $D_n C(n,0) = 0$, so...

Comment: But concerning this question, if the author wants to use $C(n,-1)$, he/she had better define it...