# Does a general formula for $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^k$ proof exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

I know that these are some existing sums that are true:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \mathcal{O}(n^2)$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \mathcal{O}(n^3)$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} = \mathcal{O}(n^4)$$

I may be butchering the definition of Big O' Notation, but I believe it describes the form of the function, i.e. the highest power of $n$ in these cases.
Is there a proof for:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^k = \mathcal{O}(n^{k+1})$$
since there seems to be this pattern?

Or even better, is there a general formulae that mirrors $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^k$$ in terms of only $n$ and $k$?

I didn't know how to phrase the question very well on Google, so I apologise if this question has been answered many times.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number maybe

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange, Syba.  You mean [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)?

Comment: also, check out [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)

Comment: The sum is give here for |x| <1$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html

Comment: Wow thanks so much to all of you!! The support came really fast!!

Comment: $O(n^{k+1})$ is straightforward - $\sum_{r=1}^n r^k\leq\sum_{r=1}^n n^k=n^{k+1}$.

Comment: singular is *formula*; plural is *formulas* or *formulae*

Comment: @Wojowu $\Theta(n^{k+1})$ is equally straightforward: the sum can be bounded from below by $\sum_{r=n/2}^nr^k \geq (n/2)\cdot(n/2)^k$.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820) for the most elegant and efficient way to obtain the closed form for sum of powers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general formula for a sum of $k^{th}$ powers of the first $n$ integers is [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula):

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^k=\dfrac {n^{k+1}}{k+1}+\dfrac12n^k+\sum_{r=2}^k\dfrac {B_r}{r!}\dfrac {k!}{(k-r+1)!}n^{k-r+1},$$ where $B_r$ is the $r^{th}$ Bernoulli number.  This is indeed a polynomial of degree $k+1$.

Comment: you can check the formulas you know as special cases (note:  $B_2=\dfrac16, B_3=0$)

Answer (score 3):

Jensen's Inequality implies
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k \ge n \left(\frac{\sum_{r=1}^{n} i}{n}\right)^k = n\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{k}.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k = \infty.$$
Also,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k < \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{k+1}}\sum_{r=1}^{n} n^k=1.$$

Consequently,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^k = \mathcal{O}(n^{k+1}).$$

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a series in terms of powers of $n$.

For the first term, note that $$\frac 1 n \sum_{r=1}^n \frac {r^k}{n^k}$$ is a Riemann sum that converges towards $$\int_0^1 x^kdx=\frac 1 {k+1}$$
Therefore 
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^k \sim \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

You can even obtain more terms in the expansion, and they involve Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Applications_of_the_Bernoulli_numbers
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m=
\frac{1}{m+1}\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m + 1}{k} B^+_k n^{m + 1 - k} = m! \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{B^+_k n^{m + 1 - k}}{k! (m+1-k)!}
$$
where, $B_k^+$ are bernouilli numbers

$  B^+_m = \sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{v=0}^k (-1)^v \binom{k}{v} \frac{(v + 1)^m}{k + 1}$
which gives you an explicit formula

Comment: Wrong formula.  "r" is not a ratio here.

Comment: @Paul I was in a hurry and didn't read it properly. I'm sorry