# Name for sums of the form $\sum_{n=0}^m n^p$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, terminology

Is there a name for these sums?

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^m n^0 &= m \\[4pt]
\sum_{n=0}^m n^1 &= \frac{m(m+1)}{2} \\[4pt]
\sum_{n=0}^m n^2 &= \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6} \\[4pt]
\sum_{n=0}^m n^3 &= \frac{m^2(m+1)(m+1)}{4}
\end{align}$$

I've reached these results experimentally so there may be errors.

Comment: [Faulhaber's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) is a good place to start.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that looks about right. Care to make that an answer?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296006/does-a-general-formula-for-sum-r-1nrk-proof-exist)

Comment: Did you really came up with these formulas  by yourself

Comment: @Milan Yes. It took a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called **power sums**; see [this MathWorld entry](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html), for example.