# Sum over the side or Vertical of Pascal's triangle / Infinite Series of Binomial coefficients summed over UPPER index

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Is there any closed form formula of even an equivalent for this binomial infinite series :

$$
F_k(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}   x^{n} 
$$
in which $|x|<1$ and k is a given integer ?
For example, $F_3(x) = x^3 + 4x^4 +10 x^5 +20 x^6 + 35 x^7 +... $

We all know that $ (1+x)^{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^{k} $

But it's *not* the same summation : in the above k is fixed and n varies from k to infinity...
In Pascal's triangle, it's a sum aver a parallel to the side of the triangle, while the classical one goes along its base.

Comment: generatingfunctionology (https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf), formula (1.5.5), p. 16.

Answer (score 5):

Take any $k∈ℕ^+$ and $x∈ℂ$ such that $|x|<1$.

$F_k(x)·(1-x) = \sum_{n=k}^∞ \binom{n}{k}x^n - \sum_{n=k+1}^∞ \binom{n-1}{k}x^n$

$= \sum_{n=k}^∞ \binom{n-1}{k-1}x^n = x·\sum_{n=k-1}^∞ \binom{n}{k-1}x^n$

$= F_{k-1}(x)·x$.

Therefore $F_k(x) = x^k·(1-x)^{-k-1}$, since $F_0(x) = (1-x)^{-1}$. Done.

~ ~ ~

Note that it is inadvisable to use differentiation of power series unless necessary, because it is not rigorous unless you invoke some uniform convergence theorems (which are much more complicated than what I used here). It is also bad to use logarithms because of the issues with branch cuts.

Finally, this is closely related to [using the forward difference operator for indefinite summation](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The sum of a power series is $C^\infty$ inside the convergence disk, and you can integrate and differentiate term by term. There is nothing non rigorous about this. Of course this theorem has to be proved, but it's classical when teaching power series, and it's done once and for all. Maybe you meant general series of functions? But it's not the situation here anyway.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I didn't say you *cannot* make it rigorous. But most people who anyhow use it *cannot* actually prove the required theorems. It is simply bad pedagogy to mislead students to use termwise differentiation without being even aware that it is not a trivially valid way to find the derivative of the power series.

Comment: Yes, it would be extremely bad pedagogy to ask students to use this without having proved the theorem in class beforehand. However, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't happen in practice (at least here in France, except maybe in some more technical courses where it may be only *stated* and not proved). That said, it's certainly not a good reason to avoid using such theorems here on MSE, or to say it's inadvisable. It's a very effective method, and that's a good reason to use it.  But hey, you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: You are lucky that you have good pedagogy in France. In many other places, most students are told this differentiation method but have totally no idea that it is non-trivial. Anyway thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

If you write the first few terms, you have:
$$S_k(x) = \frac{F_k(x)}{x^k} = \binom k k + \binom{k+1}kx + \binom{k+2}kx^2 + \cdots$$
Which becomes:
$$S_k(x) = 1 + (k+1)x + \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2!}x^2 + \cdots$$

So you're looking for the function that:
$$S_k(0) = 1$$
$$S'_k(0) = k+1$$
$$S''_k(0) = (k+1)(k+2)$$
$$S^{(n)}_k(0) = (k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n)$$

EDIT

As pointed out in the comments by Robearz, the function we're looking for is simply:
$$S_k(x) = (1 - x)^{-(k + 1)}$$

So:
$$F_k(x) = x^k(1 - x)^{-(k + 1)}$$

Comment: Thanks. Already very interesting

Comment: Doesn't $f(x)=(1-x)^{-(k+1)}$ satisfy this?

Comment: @Robearz I think it's correct, will amend my answer... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align*}{T(x)} &= \binom k k + \binom{k+1}kx + \binom{k+2}kx^2 + \cdots\\&=\binom k k + \frac{k+1}{1}\binom{k}kx + \frac{k+2}{2}\binom{k+1}kx^2 + \cdots
\\&=xT(x)+\binom k k + \frac{k}{1}\binom{k}kx + \frac{k}{2}\binom{k+1}kx^2 + \cdots\end{align*}$$

$$\implies (1-x)T(x)=\binom k k + \frac{k}{1}\binom{k}kx + \frac{k}{2}\binom{k+1}kx^2 + \cdots$$
Differentiating both sides
$$\implies (1-x)T'(x)-T(x)= kT(x)$$
$$\implies (1-x)T'(x)= (k+1)T(x)$$
$$\frac{dT(x)}{T(x)}=\frac{(k+1)dx}{1-x}$$
$$\implies \ln(T(x))=-(k+1)\ln(1-x)+C$$
$$\implies T(x)(1-x)^{k+1}=C$$
$T(0)=1$
$$\implies T(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$
$$\implies F_k(x)=x^kT(x)=\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$$

Comment: Wow, very impressive . Thanks

Comment: This appears in the Fourier Series of $\frac{1}{1 - a * sin(x)} $ for [a| <1

With your results the Fourier coefficients of $e^{i k x}$ would be something like $ \frac{a^k} { 2^k (1-a)^{k+1}} $

Comment: ... Which gives a good expression for $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{sin( k x )}{ 1 - a sin(x)} dx $

Comment: I have edited my answer. Its seems that the sum is not convergent.

Comment: Errr strange. Because the "formal" calculation seemed right though !

Comment: And where it comes from, ie this Fourier series coefficient of an periodic-homographic function seems perfectly regular...

Comment: The claim in the first line doesn't sound true. For any fixed $k$, if only $|x|<1$, then the $x^i$ factor falls away to $0$ _exponentially_ while $\binom{i}{k}$ grows only _polynomially_.

Comment: @Troposphere Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my answer.