# Determining whether a sequence is a "raikage" sequence beforehand

Tags: number-theory

Here is a fun question:
What comes next?
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 57, 99, 163, ??

If you are done trying, find the answer in the image.[image]

So here we needed to find the difference of the consecutive terms of the sequence repeatatively until we reached a constant sequence.

[Normally, i call this sequence an AP of degree 4, as after finding the difference sequence 4 times we get a constant sequence, but i don't know about the terminology used in other countries, so i will define this as some 'raikage' sequence.]

A 'raikage' sequence is a sequence in which after finding the difference series some k times we get a constant sequence.

For example, the given example is a raikage sequence,  while the sequence 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64..... is not as even after finding the difference sequence infinite number of time we won't get a constant sequence.

How can we predict beforehand without calculating the difference sequence whether a sequence is raikage or not?

My try: i took a, b, c, d, e and so on as a random sequence.  Then i tried to find the difference sequence, in hope of getting a feasible form, but this did not help in any way. In the end, no progress.

Comment: It's just a polynomial... as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820).